# SQL Error: Insert Query producing error (Column names surrounded with quotes)

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

A very simple insert command in my code for sql, originally made with node js, I moved it to php for simplicity. Then I changed all my variables to hardcoded values. This is the code along with the results:

Code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "****", "****", "****"); // assume this works
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ('username', 'email', 'profilePic') VALUES ('awd', 'awd@awd.awd', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, "http://localhost:3000/public/files/avatar/2ede50c0-d4b9-11e8-9635-617abdd05393.png")."')";
echo $query."<br>";
if (!mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}

?>
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO `users` ('username', 'email', 'profilePic') VALUES ('awd', 'awd@awd.awd', 'http://localhost:3000/public/files/avatar/2ede50c0-d4b9-11e8-9635-617abdd05393.png')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username', 'email', 'profilePic') VALUES ('awd', 'awd@awd.awd', 'http://localho' at line 1
```

Why is it throwing an error after I used `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? In node js, I also tried using `db.escape()`, which also failed. How do I fix the error? Php or Node Js answers are both accepted, thank you in advanced.

Solution:

> Column names should not have anything surrounding them, to make the sql query work, simply remove the single quotes surrounding the column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ('username', 'email', 'profilePic') VALUES ('awd', 'awd@awd.awd', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, "http://localhost:3000/public/files/avatar/2ede50c0-d4b9-11e8-9635-617abdd05393.png")."')";
```

With this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, email, profilePic) VALUES ('awd', 'awd@awd.awd', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, "http://localhost:3000/public/files/avatar/2ede50c0-d4b9-11e8-9635-617abdd05393.png")."')";
```

Column names do not have anything surrounding them, a very simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I think you need to surround column names with backtick.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `profilePic`)
VALUES ('awd',
        'awd@awd.awd',
        '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, 
         "http://localhost:3000/public/files/avatar/2ede50c0-d4b9-11e8-9635-617abdd05393.png")."')";
```

Comment: I cant believe I didnt see this lol, you shouldn't have any backticks, or quotes surrounding the column name, this was a very simple error on my part, I think I will remove the question.